# Calculate the size of label/search/filter?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

Are there any ways in Gmail to see the total size of selected messages - that is, a label, search or a filter (filters are basically just static searches anyway, and I use filters to automatically apply a label on many incoming messages)?